# Make table 100 percent in width and add solid vertical divider

Tags: tables, captions, vertical-alignment, width

**Problem:**

Making the table 100% in width and adding vertical lines only for letters A-K.

**Minimal working example (MWE):**

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{11}{c}}
\toprule
\bfseries Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K \\
\midrule
\bfseries Text 1
\\
\bfseries Text 2
\\
\bfseries Text 3
\\
\bfseries Text 4
\\
\bfseries Text 5
\\
\bfseries Text 6
\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{l}{A: Caption 1}\\
\multicolumn{11}{l}{B: Caption 2}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
```

Current output:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. What is the correct way to make the table stretch 100%?
2. What needs to be modified in order to add vertical lines for the columns A-K?
3. Is there a way which captions can be stacked 4 x 4 x 2 horizontally instead of 11 vertically?

Comment: I don't se what you mean for your last requirement, ‘stacked 4×4×2’?

Comment: @Bernard I meant that ABCD should be under each other, then to the right of it there should be EFGH under each other then IJK to the right of EFGH under each other.

Comment: You probably want to use tabularx,  You can also use \resizebox from the graphicx package, but that will change the size of the letters as well.  And yes, you can put more than one \multicolumn into a row.

Comment: You should maybe look at something like `threeparttable` if the captions are something like notes. Don't use vertical rules. If, for whatever reason, you must use them, then don't use the `booktabs` rules as the result will look even worse then just using vertical rules with default `\hline`s.

Comment: By the way, that's not an MWE because it cannot be compiled as it stands.

Comment: So it should be stacked rather 4×4×3, I guess. Should the vertical lines be only  for the row of letters?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, my apologies.. it should be 4x4x3. Vertical lines only for the letters.

Comment: I'm not sure to have well understood where the vertical lines have to be, but it's easy to modify.

Comment: @Bernard Neither am I now I've seen your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tabularx` to get the full width table, which also shows how to combine several `\multicolumn`s within a row. This addresses questions (1) and (3).

[image: full width table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-12}
    & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K \\
    \midrule
     Text 1
    \\
     Text 2
    \\
     Text 3
    \\
     Text 4
    \\
     Text 5
    \\
     Text 6
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    A: Caption 1\newline B: Caption 2\newline C: Caption 3\newline D: Caption 4 & E: Caption 5\newline F: Caption 6\newline G: Caption 7\newline H: Caption 8 & I: Caption 9\newline J: Caption 10\newline K: Caption 11\\
      \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I strongly recommend ***not*** using vertical rules. However, if for some reason you must do this (i.e. you have no choice), then you need to replace `booktabs` enhanced rules with LaTeX's defaults. This addresses question (2). For example:

[image: adding vertical rules]

```
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \hline
    Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{D} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{E} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{G} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{H} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{J} & K \\
    \hline
     Text 1
    \\
     Text 2
    \\
     Text 3
    \\
     Text 4
    \\
     Text 5
    \\
     Text 6
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    A: Caption 1\newline B: Caption 2\newline C: Caption 3\newline D: Caption 4 & E: Caption 5\newline F: Caption 6\newline G: Caption 7\newline H: Caption 8 & I: Caption 9\newline J: Caption 10\newline K: Caption 11\\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
```

If you do not mind abusing `booktabs` and having gaps above and below your vertical rules, you could, in this case, just about get away with combining them. For example:

[image: abusing <code>booktabs</code>]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-12}
    & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{D} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{E} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{G} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{H} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{J} & K \\
    \midrule
     Text 1
    \\
     Text 2
    \\
     Text 3
    \\
     Text 4
    \\
     Text 5
    \\
     Text 6
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    A: Caption 1\newline B: Caption 2\newline C: Caption 3\newline D: Caption 4 & E: Caption 5\newline F: Caption 6\newline G: Caption 7\newline H: Caption 8 & I: Caption 9\newline J: Caption 10\newline K: Caption 11\\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

This responds to the question asked in the comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{10}{Y|}Y}
    \hline
    Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K \\
    \hline
     Agora Voting & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
    \\
     Text 2 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 3 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 4 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 5 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 6 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    A: Caption 1\newline B: Caption 2\newline C: Caption 3\newline D: Caption 4 & E: Caption 5\newline F: Caption 6\newline G: Caption 7\newline H: Caption 8 & I: Caption 9\newline J: Caption 10\newline K: Caption 11\\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: longer vertical rules]

## EDIT AGAIN

This is a response to another two follow-up questions in the comments.

By default, captions are centred. This is not an effect of my code. It is just the default. You can customise the formatting of captions using the `caption` package. In the example below, I configure captions to be typeset as justified paragraphs.

If you want some columns to be of specified width, you can use `p{width}` as usual. Provided at least one column is of type `X` and the total width does not exceed to total width specified for the table, `tabularx` will figure things out appropriately.

In the following, I assume that the column for criterion A should be 50pt wide and that for criterion F should be 10pt wide. All other criteria are to be typeset in columns of equal width.

[image: custom caption and column widths]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}}y{50pt}|*{4}{Y|}y{10pt}|*{4}{Y|}Y}
    \hline
    Solution & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K \\
    \hline
     Agora Voting & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
    \\
     Text 2 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 3 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 4 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 5 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
     Text 6 &&&&&&&&&&
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    A: Caption 1\newline B: Caption 2\newline C: Caption 3\newline D: Caption 4 & E: Caption 5\newline F: Caption 6\newline G: Caption 7\newline H: Caption 8 & I: Caption 9\newline J: Caption 10\newline K: Caption 11\\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, much appreciated. However, I am wondering: how would I go about to make the vertical lines go all the way down across the table and not just the letters? (apologies for saying only for the letters, I was mistaken). A secondary wish, how do I increase the space between text 1-6?

Comment: @kexxcream Please see edit.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a small issue left. Some of the vertical lines are "faded" or not as solid as the rest. What could be wrong?

Comment: @kexxcream That's just my viewer. They are really all the same width and weight.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that when zooming in. Mission accomplished! Thanks for being the hero of the day :)

Comment: @kexxcream If I zoom in on the original PDF, they all look equal, but the image has to be 400-800% depending on the amount of detail involved. So when I post an image here, the PNG reflects what things look like at a more normal zoom level, with the result that line widths tend to look unequal. (Sometimes lines don't appear to be there at all.) So, yes. Just the PNG is misleading.

Comment: Now I see another problem, try replacing Text 1 with the following: Agora Voting & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ - you will notice that column G and K is not the same as the other columns. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: @kexxcream Oops. See edit. I'll correct the earlier ones after but I've fixed the edited table which is the one you want.

Comment: Sorry to bother too much with my issues. How can I, like before, get the new solution left-aligned and also control the width of each column?

Comment: @kexxcream The table is centred because of the `\centering` but that was there in your original example. You can replace some of the `X` columns with `p{whatever}` if you want to control the width. So long as you have at least one `X` and the total width doesn't exceed the total width of the tabular, `tabularx` will calculate appropriate values.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My intention is to have the table centered and hence the \centering but the captions should be left-aligned. I know you are refering to p{XXX\textwidth} but I am not sure how I should integrate it with the current solution. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: @kexxcream See further edit. However, do note that really, the site works best with a one-question-per-question formula. It is fine to ask follow-up questions and to link to this one if that would be helpful. But it makes things easier for people to find if distinct issues are dealt with in distinct questions and answers. For example, configuring the format of captions is really a different question.

Comment: Will keep that under careful consideration in the future. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions, if I've well understood what you want. They're both based on `tabularx`. The first consists in adding a second tabularx environment for the captions; the second uses a `multicols` environment. The `makecell` package is used for a common formatting of column heads and some vertical padding of rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, array, makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
  \makegapedcells
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{11}{X}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-12}
    Solution & \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} & \thead{D} & \thead{E} & \thead{F} & \thead{G} & \thead{ H} & \thead{I} & \thead{J} & \thead{K} \\
    \midrule
    Text 1
    \\
    Text 2
    \\
    Text 3
    \\
    Text 4
    \\
    Text 5
    \\
    Text 6
    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \setlength\columnseprule{0.6pt}
  \setlength\columnsep{2em}
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    A: Caption 1 \\
    B: Caption 2 \\
    C: Caption 3 \\
    D: Caption 4 \\
    E: Caption 5 \\
    F: Caption 6 \\
    G: Caption 7 \\
    H: Caption 8 \\
    I : Caption 9 \\
    J: Caption 10 \\
    K: Caption 11 \\
  \end{multicols}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}
\vskip3ex
\begin{table}[!hbp]
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  {\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{11}{X}}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{11}{c}{\bfseries Criteria} \\
      \cmidrule(l){2-12}
      Solution & \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} & \thead{D} & \thead{E} & \thead{F} & \thead{G} & \thead{ H} & \thead{I} & \thead{J} & \thead{K} \\
      \midrule
      Text 1
      \\
      Text 2
      \\
      Text 3
      \\
      Text 4
      \\
      Text 5
      \\
      Text 6
      \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
    \addlinespace[3ex]
    A: Caption 1 & E: Caption 5 & I : Caption 9 \\
    B: Caption 2 & F: Caption 6 & J: Caption 10 \\
    C: Caption 3 & G: Caption 7 & K: Caption 11 \\
    D: Caption 4 & H: Caption 8
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Text text text}\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]